# How to send EOF to stdin in paramiko?

Tags: python, stdin, eof, paramiko

I would like to execute some program through ssh and redirect its input from a file. The behaviour of the following code:

```
channel.exec_command('cat')
with open('mumu', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    nbytes = 0
    while nbytes < len(text):
        sent = channel.send(text[nbytes:])
        if sent == 0:
            break
        nbytes += sent
```

should be equivalent to (assuming public-key authentication):

```
 ssh user@host cat < mumu
```

However the application hangs waiting for more input. I think this happens because the stdin stream is never closed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`shutdown()`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.shutdown) (or `shutdown_write()`) on the channel.

Comment: what happens to stdout and stderr then?

Answer (score 4):

Call the method: `channel.shutdown_write()`.

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't use a channel explicitly I had to do it a bit differently. For whomever might find it helpful:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
connection = client.connect(hostname)
stdin, stdout, stderr = connection.exec_command('cat')
stdin.write('spam')
# Close the channel, this results in an EOF for `cat`.
stdin.channel.shutdown_write()
# stdout/stderr are readable.
print(stdout.read().decode())
print(stderr.read().decode())
```